# MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA is empty for files on USB-Drive

Tags: android, media-player, mediastore

I'm searching Musicfiles via

```
proj = new String[] {[...],
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
                    };
Cursor musiccursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1", null, null);

[...]

int ixdata      = musiccursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

[...]

while(musiccursor.moveToNext()) {
  [...]
  String data     = musiccursor.getString(ixdata);
```

with files on /mnt/sdcard everything works just fine, but unfortunately with files in /mnt/USB data seems to be empty.

What's even worse is that the mediaplayer works with the content-URI of files in /mnt/sdcard (i.e. content://media/external/audio/media/120) but not with the content-URIs of files in /mnt/USB (i.e. content://media/external/audio/media/530).

The files are alright, i can play them fine when i give the mediaplayer the absolute path to i.e. /mnt/USB/testfile.mp3

Even weirder: Album, Artist, Title etc. are read without problems from the files on the USB-Drive

anyone an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've asked myself the very same question, but I did not manage to find the reason why the mediastore contains rows with empty data.
What I came up with is adding a "where clause" in the query to the mediastore by not-selecting the items with and empty data field (filtering the empty data source).

```
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
  MY_COLUMNS, 
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "<> ''",
  null,
  SORT_ORDER);
```

where

- MY_COLUMNS is a String[] containing my columns'names
- SORT_ORDER is my sorting order option